# How to implement file manager or file explorer on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My website will generate lots of files and folders under my public folder

and I wanna provide user to download or zip all contents in a folder via web page,

How to implement it in a easier way ? any idea? Thanks

My files structure

```
.
└── streaming
    ├── 2014-04-01_17-35-32
    ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-10
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-10.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-10.mp4
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-10.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-10.txt
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-15.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-15.mp4
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-15.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-15.txt
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-18.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-18.mp4
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-18.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-18.txt
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-22.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-22.mp4
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-22.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-22.txt
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-24.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-24.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-24.txt
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-25.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-25.mp4
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-25.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-25.txt
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-31.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-31.mp4
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-31.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-10-31.txt
    │   └── 2014-04-02_16-10-36.mp4
    ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-46
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-46.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-46.mp4
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-46.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-46.txt
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-49.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-49.mp4
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-49.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-49.txt
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-50.log
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-50.mp4
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-50.png
    │   ├── 2014-04-02_16-11-50.txt
    │   └── 2014-04-02_16-11-55.mp4
```

Comment: So would you like real "Windows explorer" style, or just ability to download individual folder?

Comment: Have ability to download and move in folders on web page, Just like the style of  github files. (it's enough)